# Selecting a Specific Array Element in LuaTeX?

Tags: macros, luatex, lua, directlua

I need to create a command that goes `\MyCommand{x,y}` or `\MyCommand{x,y,z}` (both ways should be possible), where `x`, `y`, and `z` are three numbers. It should give the output `\begin{matrix}x\\y\end{matrix}` and `\begin{matrix}x\\y\\z\end{matrix}`, respectively.

And the command should have just one argument in a comma separated form as represented.

I'm not very familiar with using Lua code in LaTeX. But I tried the following any way.

```
\newcommand*{\MyCommand}[1]{%
\directlua {
  str={#1}
    if str[3]==nil then
       tex.sprint([[\begin{matrix}]] .. str[1] .. [[\\]] .. str[2] .. [[\\]] .. [[\end{matrix}]])
    else
       tex.sprint([[\begin{matrix}]] .. str[1] .. [[\\]] .. str[2] .. [[\\]] .. str[3] .. [[\end{matrix}]])
    end
}
}%
```

Please let me know where I am mistaken, or how I can develop this command.

I am using MikTeX distribution and LuaLaTeX output mode.

Here's a MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand*{\MyCommand}[1]{%
\directlua {
  str={#1}
    if str[3]==nil then
       tex.sprint([[\begin{matrix}]] .. str[1] .. [[\\]] .. str[2] .. [[\\]] .. [[\end{matrix}]])
    else
       tex.sprint([[\begin{matrix}]] .. str[1] .. [[\\]] .. str[2] .. [[\\]] .. str[3] .. [[\end{matrix}]])
    end
}
}%

\begin{document}

$\MyCommand{x,y}$\\
$\MyCommand{x,y,z}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: do you need lua for some reason not shown (you could just as easily do it in tex) but if you just want lua answers that's OK.

Comment: If there is another way that would preserve the command as it is (`\MyCommand{x,y}` or `\MyCommand{x,y,z}`), it would be great.

Comment: It's just a chance to better understand Lua though .. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would just do this in TeX (note you omitted `amsmath`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand*{\MyCommand}[1]{\begin{matrix}\relax\zz#1,\end{matrix}}
\def\zz#1,#2{#1\ifx\end#2\else\expandafter\\\expandafter\zz\fi#2}

\begin{document}


$\MyCommand{x,y}$

$\MyCommand{x,y,z}$

\end{document}
```

For the Lua version you need to remember that macros expand before being passed to lua so you could put `\unexpanded{....}` around the full argument but then you also would need the elements of your table to be the lua string `'x'` not (as you have it) the undefined lua variable `x` so you would need an extra layer of string quoting if done that way. Or more simply treat the whole thing as a string and just replace `,` by `\\` using a Lua replace

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand*{\MyCommand}[1]{%
\begin{matrix}%
\directlua{
s=string.gsub('\luaescapestring{#1}',',','\string\\\string\\')
tex.sprint(s)}%
\end{matrix}}

\begin{document}



$\MyCommand{x,y}$

$\MyCommand{x,y,z}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: note both these versions allow any number of commas not just 2 or 3.

Answer (score 6):

Another simple version (but with `expl3`). For the image I have replaced `matrix` with `pmatrix`. It's extensible too (comma list element count is not specified).

[image: matrix]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand { \MyCommand } { m }
    {
        \begin{matrix}
            \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { #1 }
            \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { \\ }
        \end{matrix}
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\MyCommand{x,y}$

$\MyCommand{x,y,z}$

$\MyCommand{x,y,z,a,b}$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following answer is very similar to [David's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/378075/5001). The main difference is the use of the [luacode](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/luatex/latex/luacode) package, which provides an environment called `luacode`. Inside a `luacode` environment, most of TeX's "special" characters -- `#`, `$`, `%`, `^`, `&`, `{`, `}`, `~` -- can be entered directly. (This is particularly useful for the `%` character, which as its own special meaning in some of Lua's pattern-matching and math-related functions. The only one of TeX's "special" characters that needs, well, special treatment is the backslash character, `\`: it has to be entered as `\\`. To enter a double-backslash, one has to type `\\\\`. Finally, Lua-style line comments are possible inside a `luacode` environment.

On a separate note: Observe the use of the macro `\luastringN`, which is also provided by the `luacode` package, to pass the argument of the LaTeX macro to the Lua function. In my view, `\luastringN{#1}` is easier to remember (and certainly easier on the eyes...) than `'\luaescapestring{\unexpanded{#1}}'` is. :-)

[image]

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode} % for 'luacode' env. and '\luastringN' macro

%% Lua-side code
\begin{luacode}
function comma2double_backslash ( s )
   -- replace all commas with double-backslashes
   tex.sprint ((s:gsub ( ',' , '\\\\' )))
end
\end{luacode}
%% TeX-side code
\newcommand*{\MyCommand}[1]{%
   \begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
   \directlua{comma2double_backslash ( \luastringN{#1} )}
   \end{array}%
}

\begin{document}
$\MyCommand{x,y}$

$\MyCommand{x,y,z}$
\end{document}
```